# HTML5 DeviceOrientation event returning incorrect values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, device-orientation

I'm trying to get the correct alpha, beta, and gamma values from the device orientation event. I've looked at a few tutorials, but they all seem to have the same problem. When the beta value reaches around 90 degrees on a device, both the alpha and gamma values become erratic and jump around randomly when they should be staying constant.

You can easily test this by loading [this example](http://mekya.com/labs/device_orientation.html) on a phone and angling your device so that the beta value hovers around 90. My question is how do I get the correct values for alpha and gamma when this occurs?

Are there any examples or resources I can use to fix this? I would prefer not to use a library if possible.

Comment: Joe, I accessed the example in chrome for android and I see no erratic values

Comment: This depends on the device You are using and its accelerometer accuracy . In order to make the readings  more consistant You could use arithmetic mean on the readings

Comment: @gal007 It might be specific to iOS devices. I tested on iPhone 5, 6, 7 and could reproduce the problem every time.

Comment: @SebastianKrysiak That wouldn't work properly as the values jump from any number between 0 and 360.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609518/fixing-ios-safari-javascript-deviceorientation-event-irregularity may or may not be relevant

Comment: This seems like something that ought to be reported as an issue at https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: @sideshowbarker That looks like the same problem, but there's no definitive solution there unfortunately.

Comment: Yup. So yeah the best way to get attention from the Safari developers on it would be to raise an issue at https://bugs.webkit.org/